# Need help getting at least +/-10 V from op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm new to here and I did already some of the research but cannot really find an answer. I'm not very familiar with op-amps.

I have wired a LM358 op-amp as per the below example schematic in the [MCP4725 DAC datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22039b.pdf). The problem is that I'm getting only +2.7 V all the way to -2.2 V (I guess because I used 22 kΩ resistor instead of 20 kΩ) on the 12-bit DAC resolution.

However, I used bipolar supply with +/-15 V, and I was expecting the output voltage to be somewhere close to the 15 V both ways, or at least 10 V. Can somebody please explain what am I missing in order to reach my voltage output? Is the op-amp chosen wrong? If so, can you please recommend a device to use?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

[image: Example 8-3 - Digitally-Controlled Bipolar Voltage Source - from MCP4725 datasheet]

---

- R1 and R4 are 22kΩ
- R2 and R3 are 10kΩ

Comment: The MCP4725 is operated with Vdd = + 5V. It is output Vout could be not higher than 5 V. The first formula gives the value 5(4095/4096) V = 4.9988 V. You have to calculate the values of R1, R2, R3 and R4 to get an output of -10 to + 10 V. You need an amplification of 4 to get -10 to + 10 V from 0 to 4.9988 V.

Comment: I see now, the datasheet stated gain is 0.5 based on 10k/20k resistors.  Am i right?

Answer (score 5):

The circuit is bogus.

The opamp and its four resistors have the general form of a difference amplifier. Since V<sub>OUT</sub> can never be greater than V<sub>DD</sub>, it's simply impossible for the output of the opamp to ever be greater than V<sub>DD</sub>, no matter what you do with the resistor values.

At a minimum, you'd have to add a resistor between the opamp "–" input and ground, in order to create the required offset. If you make this resistor equal to R1, then the effective reference voltage will be V<sub>DD</sub>/2 — the middle of the range of V<sub>OUT</sub>. This means that the differential input voltage (between V<sub>OUT</sub> and V<sub>DD</sub>/2) can range between -2.5V and +2.5V.

Then, R3 should be half this value. In order to get a ±10V output range (from a differential input of ±2.5V) you need a gain of 4, so R2 and R4 should be 4× the value of R3 (i.e., 2× the value of R1).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fauGob.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Any chance you could post a diagram of what you just said? Do i understand that i keep everything as per my above diagram, and than add that resistor to "-" on the opamp? I would appreciate if you could also add the values to reach the +/- 10v. Thanks

Comment: See edit above. If you use 22k instead of 20k, you'll get an output that goes from -11V to +11V. R3 can be two 10k resistors in parallel.